# How to load webpage without using www

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, cname, no-www

Im hosting on 000webhost. If I type my `www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com` it loads. If I type `example.com` or `http://example.com` it doesn't load. Is there a fix for this please? As this is particularly important for mobile phone users.

I have been in contact with `godaddy.com` but the guy tries to do what I have tried already:

```
CNAME -- www -- example.000webhost.com -- TTL 1 hour (this one goes in)
CNAME -- www -- @ -- TTL 1 hour (this one refuses to work) Its rejected by Godaddy
```

Im getting an error message "please contact Godaddy support", but this is not working as they don't know how to solve the issue.

Comment: sorry for the (an actual dot) comments but It would not let me post otherwise

Comment: Use backticks to format inline code and URLs. (Should be a button on the editor as well.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is about configuring a website, which is on-topic at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com